# Azure Bot Framework How To Automate Add/Update Facebook Channel Page Id & Token

Tags: azure, botframework

Everytime when new customer register and authenticated my bot using Facebook app, I need to manually input the page ID & access token on Azure Bot Facebook channel in order to have their bot working.

Since now Azure Bot able to put multiple facebook page id on a single bot, how can I automate the process above using REST api / any automating tools recommended?

I tried for
[Azure Management BotService SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.BotService/0.9.1-preview) & Azure Cli, but both of them seem only able to create / delete a channel directly.

Any idea's on how it can be achieved?

Comment: I do not think automation as you are looking for is possible at the moment.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I just got found out that the Azure Resource Management API maybe is the possible way for doing this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7564, at the moment seem like there's bug on that, once it ready I think we can fully automate this process. :)